# Bundler not ignoring the gems in the group I pass the --without option to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am trying to bundle install without rubygems bringing in `nokogumbo` and running it in the install.

In my gemfile, I have

```
...
group :nonbundled do
  gem 'nokogumbo', '1.4.13'
end
...
```

run `bundle install --without nonbundled` still searching for gem

```
...    
Using jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1
Using jwt 1.5.6
Using koala 3.0.0
Using mini_magick 4.5.1
Using ruby-progressbar 1.8.1
Using minitest-reporters 1.1.9
Using multi_xml 0.6.0
Fetching nokogumbo 1.4.13
Installing nokogumbo 1.4.13 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
...
```

What is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. is it getting installed as a dependancy of any other gem? 2. if you remove it totally from Gem file and do bundle, is it still getting installed?

Comment: Yes. It is a dependency on rails-html-sanitizer gem and has something to do with nokogiri too I think.

Comment: Yes, it is not in gemfile at all except in the `nonbundled` group. It is also dependant on the rgroove `sanitze` gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in comment that `nokogumbo` is a dependency of another gem. Because of that it is getting installed.

if you use `--without` argument while doing bundle install, and if the gem which was supposed to be skipped is present as a dependancy in another Gem it will be installed.

[reference for above](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html#INSTALLING-GROUPS)

Comment: I wanted to get around, that. You know of a way besides bundle? I'll have a look.